# insert column into table, use existing column values as default for existing rows

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to add a column to an exsting table.

```
ALTER TABLE statuses ADD updated int(11) default NULL
```

the above line adds the desired column to my table, instead of NULL as default value, I want to use the value of the column 'created'. So each row will get the column 'updated' and is filled with its 'own' column 'created'.

How can I do this?

example:

```
id - created
1  - 12345678
2  - 87654321
3  - 12121212
```

now insert the new column 'updated', the table should be like:

```
id - created - updated
1  - 12345678 - 12345678 
2  - 87654321 - 87654321
3  - 12121212 - 12121212
```

Comment: Can u Please explain with a sample?

Comment: aye, I've added an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, not in a single statement.

You'll have to run two statements:

```
ALTER TABLE statuses ADD updated int(11);

UPDATE  statuses
SET     updated = created;
```